# Could a @Scheduled non-blocking ServerSocketChannel accept() miss incoming TCP messages?

Tags: spring, tcp, scheduled-tasks, nio, serversocket

During code review, a colleague suggested changing a blocking TCP server to use a non-blocking `java.nio.ServerSocketChannel` with a `@Scheduled` method that repeatedly checks for new messages via `accept()`.

My question is simple: Whatever interval is chosen, is there a risk of missing messages? *To take an extreme example, let's say the checking interval is hugely increased to 1 hour and 1000 messages are sent during that time. `accept()` would only receive 1 message - so would the other 999 be missed? And if so, would they fail silently or would the TCP clients not be able to send them?*

Comment: Why scheduled? That seems like a hacky workaround for whatever is really wanted, which might be something like RxJava.

Comment: I guess because we are using Spring and have other @Scheduled beans so it fits the pattern. As for RxJava, thanks for the suggestion but would prefer not to bring in any further 3rd party libraries if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During code review, a colleague suggested changing a blocking TCP server to use a non-blocking `java.nio.ServerSocketChannel` with a `@Scheduled` method that repeatedly checks for new messages via `accept()`.

Why? Incoming connections don't occur according to a schedule. What problem is that intended to solve?

> My question is simple: Whatever interval is chosen, is there a risk of missing messages?

Yes.

> *To take an extreme example, let's say the checking interval is hugely increased to 1 hour and 1000 messages are sent during that time. `accept()` would only receive 1 message - so would the other 999 be missed?

There's a backlog queue, so you won't miss 999, but you'll certainly miss quite a few. Exactly how many is indeterminate.

> And if so, would they fail silently or would the TCP clients not be able to send them?*

The TCP clients would get connect errors: connection refusals or timeouts, depending on the server platform.

Don't do this. It's completely and utterly pointless. It doesn't solve any problem and it creates many more.

Comment: Thanks. So to confirm, is your recommendation to keep a blocking accept()? Do you know whether this would have any bad implications on CPU usage, e.g. behind the scenes is there a looping going on before the message is received and if so, could this be a problem given the TCP server runs in a single dedicated thread?

Comment: @SteveChambers (a) Yes (b) no. It's a blocking call, not a looping or polling call. You'll have to tell us what you mean by the last sentence. A blocking TCP server has a thread dedicated to an accept loop, and that thread starts a new thread per incoming connection. If you haven't built it that way, start now.

Comment: Re: Last sentence, I think you've already answered it with your (b) response but had the answer been that it was looping, would this matter? I.e. is it a bad idea to have a thread that quickly loops round in a circle waiting/testing for something? (Am guessing the answer is yes here).

Comment: Of course, but the solution to that in non-blocking mode is a Selector, not a scheduler.